# Create variable combining subgroups within each group using R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a data frame in the following way:

```
dat <- data.frame(v1=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C","C"), v2=c("G1","G1","G1","G2","G1","G3","G3","G4"))
```

I need to create a new variable indicating all subgroups (v2) within each group(v1) so that at the end my data would be in the following way:

```
  v1 v2 which_subgroups
1  A G1 "G1"
2  A G1 "G1"
3  B G1 "G1, G2"
4  B G2 "G1, G2"
5  C G1 "G1, G3, G4"
6  C G3 "G1, G3, G4"
7  C G3 "G1, G3, G4"
8  C G4 "G1, G3, G4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` package & `paste`

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  mutate(sub_group = paste(sort(unique(v2)), collapse = ", "))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   v1 [3]
#>   v1    v2    sub_group 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     
#> 1 A     G1    G1        
#> 2 A     G1    G1        
#> 3 B     G1    G1, G2    
#> 4 B     G2    G1, G2    
#> 5 C     G1    G1, G3, G4
#> 6 C     G3    G1, G3, G4
#> 7 C     G3    G1, G3, G4
#> 8 C     G4    G1, G3, G4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

BaseR way

```r
dat <- data.frame(v1=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C","C"), v2=c("G1","G1","G1","G2","G1","G3","G3","G4"))

dat$out <- ave(dat$v2, dat$v1, FUN = function(x) toString(unique(x)))

dat
#>   v1 v2        out
#> 1  A G1         G1
#> 2  A G1         G1
#> 3  B G1     G1, G2
#> 4  B G2     G1, G2
#> 5  C G1 G1, G3, G4
#> 6  C G3 G1, G3, G4
#> 7  C G3 G1, G3, G4
#> 8  C G4 G1, G3, G4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>